# parsing identifiers except keywords

Tags: c++, parsing, c++14, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-x3

I am struggeling writing a identifier parser, which parses a alphanum string which is not a keyword.
the keywords are all in a table:

```
struct keywords_t : x3::symbols<x3::unused_type> {
    keywords_t() {
        add("for", x3::unused)
                ("in", x3::unused)
                ("while", x3::unused);
    }
} const keywords;
```

and the parser for a identifier should be this:

```
auto const identifier_def =       
            x3::lexeme[
                (x3::alpha | '_') >> *(x3::alnum | '_')
            ];
```

now i try to combine these so an identifier parser fails on parsing a keyword.
I tried it like this:

```
auto const identifier_def =       
                x3::lexeme[
                    (x3::alpha | '_') >> *(x3::alnum | '_')
                ]-keywords;
```

and this:

```
auto const identifier_def =       
                x3::lexeme[
                    (x3::alpha | '_') >> *(x3::alnum | '_') - keywords
                ];
```

it works on most inputs but if a string starts with a keyword like like `int, whilefoo, forbar` the parser fails to parse this strings.
how can i get this parser correct?

Comment: You may want to look at LLVM's libtooling : http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LibTooling.html

Comment: I also expected such a semantics of `operator -`, but it is rather different. There is some related discussion [here](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Parser-operator-Difference-td4675788.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your problem is caused by the semantics of the difference operator in Spirit. When you have `a - b` Spirit does the following:

- check whether `b` matches:

  - if it does, `a - b` fails and nothing is parsed.
  - if `b` fails then it checks whether `a` matches:

    - if `a` fails, `a - b` fails and nothing is parsed.
    - if `a` succeeds, `a - b` succeeds and parses whatever `a` parses.

In your case (`unchecked_identifier - keyword`) as long as the identifier starts with a keyword, `keyword` will match and your parser will fail. So you need to exchange `keyword` with something that matches whenever a distinct keyword is passed, but fails whenever the keyword is followed by something else. The `not predicate` (`!`) can help with that.

```
auto const distinct_keyword = x3::lexeme[ keyword >> !(x3::alnum | '_') ];
```

Full Sample ([Running on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e20c7695b6c20e5e)):

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_X3_DEBUG
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>

namespace parser {
    namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

    struct keywords_t : x3::symbols<x3::unused_type> {
        keywords_t() {
            add("for", x3::unused)
                    ("in", x3::unused)
                    ("while", x3::unused);
        }
    } const keywords;

    x3::rule<struct identifier_tag,std::string>  const identifier ("identifier");

    auto const distinct_keyword = x3::lexeme[ keywords >> !(x3::alnum | '_') ];
    auto const unchecked_identifier = x3::lexeme[(x3::alpha | x3::char_('_')) >> *(x3::alnum | x3::char_('_'))];


    auto const identifier_def = unchecked_identifier - distinct_keyword;

    //This should also work:
    //auto const identifier_def = !distinct_keyword >> unchecked_identifier


    BOOST_SPIRIT_DEFINE(identifier);

    bool is_identifier(const std::string& input)
    {
        auto iter = std::begin(input), end= std::end(input);

        bool result = x3::phrase_parse(iter,end,identifier,x3::space);

        return result && iter==end;
    }
}



int main() {

    std::cout << parser::is_identifier("fortran") << std::endl;
    std::cout << parser::is_identifier("for") << std::endl;
    std::cout << parser::is_identifier("integer") << std::endl;
    std::cout << parser::is_identifier("in") << std::endl;
    std::cout << parser::is_identifier("whileechoyote") << std::endl;
    std::cout << parser::is_identifier("while") << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that this runs without a lexer, that is, if you write

```
keyword >> *char_
```

And put in `whilefoo` it will parse `while` as `keyword` and `foo` as the `*char_`.

You can prevent that in two ways: either require to have a space after the keyword, i.e.

```
auto keyword_rule = (keyword >> x3::space);
//or if you use phrase_parse
auto keyword_rule = x3::lexeme[keyword >> x3::space];
```

The other way you described is also possible, i.e. remove the keyword from the string explicitly (I'd do it that way):

```
auto string = x3::lexeme[!keyword >> (x3::alpha | '_') >> *(x3::alnum | '_')];
```

The problem with your definition is, that it will interpret the first set of chars as the keyword, thereby choosing to not parse it at all. The 'x-y' operator means, parse x, but not y. But if you pass 'whilefoo' it will interpret 'while' as the keyword and therefor not parse at all.