# Boost Spirit - How to match a string but not substrings

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

I'm trying to write a parser using `boost::spirit` that will match an alphanumeric sequence that may also contain the _ character, but will exclude the literals *'in'* and *'out'* (`rule0`).

For example, it should match *"abc3x3_" , "_hello", "in_12", "out_in"* etc.
But should **not** match *"in"* or *"out"*.

`rule1` below is intended to achieve this.

```
typedef boost::spirit::qi::rule <const char*, string(), ascii::space_type> myRule;

myRule rule0 = qi::lit("in") | "out";  
myRule rule1 = ((qi::alpha | '_') >> *(qi::alnum | '_')) - rule0;
```

The problem is that it **doesn't** match strings that **contain** the literals from `rule0` as substrings:

For example, it doesn't match *"_in", "in_12", "out1"* etc.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38039237/parsing-identifiers-except-keywords) uses Spirit.X3 but the ideas (and the operators) apply to your problem.

Comment: There are more answers on this topic https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a85371%20keyword%20distinct e.g